# Riak java client, execute() never returns

Tags: java, riak

I've setup a riak server on ubuntu.

http://192.168.0.102:8098/ping return "OK"

I'm trying to remotely connect to it using riak java client(2.1.1) using the following code. client.execute() never returns. I'm attaching the log also.

```
public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException,
            InterruptedException, UnknownHostException {

        RiakClient client = RiakClient.newClient(8098, "192.168.0.102");

        // put some stuff

        Namespace ns = new Namespace("TestBucket");
        Location location = new Location(ns, "TestKey");

        String myData = "TestValue";

        StoreValue store = new StoreValue.Builder(myData)
        .withLocation(location).build();
        Response rv = client.execute(store);            // << NEVER GETS PAST THIS

        System.out.println("write done");

        // get some stuff
        FetchValue fv = new FetchValue.Builder(location).build();
        FetchValue.Response response = client.execute(fv);
        String obj = response.getValue(String.class);

        System.out.println(obj);
        System.out.println("fetch done");

    }

}
```

Log on the console is...

```
17:19:40.841 [main] DEBUG i.n.u.i.l.InternalLoggerFactory - Using SLF4J as the default logging framework
17:19:40.865 [main] DEBUG i.n.c.MultithreadEventLoopGroup - -Dio.netty.eventLoopThreads: 16
17:19:40.891 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.Buffer.address: available
17:19:40.892 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - sun.misc.Unsafe.theUnsafe: available
17:19:40.893 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - sun.misc.Unsafe.copyMemory: available
17:19:40.894 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - direct buffer constructor: available
17:19:40.894 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.Bits.unaligned: available, true
17:19:40.894 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(long, int): available
17:19:40.896 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.Cleaner0 - java.nio.ByteBuffer.cleaner(): available
17:19:40.896 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - Platform: Windows
17:19:40.897 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - Java version: 8
17:19:40.897 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.noUnsafe: false
17:19:40.897 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - sun.misc.Unsafe: available
17:19:40.898 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.noJavassist: false
17:19:40.899 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - Javassist: unavailable
17:19:40.899 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - You don't have Javassist in your class path or you don't have enough permission to load dynamically generated classes.  Please check the configuration for better performance.
17:19:40.899 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.tmpdir: C:\Users\Rakesh\AppData\Local\Temp (java.io.tmpdir)
17:19:40.900 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.bitMode: 32 (sun.arch.data.model)
17:19:40.900 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.noPreferDirect: false
17:19:40.900 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - io.netty.maxDirectMemory: 259522560 bytes
17:19:40.921 [main] DEBUG io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop - -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization: false
17:19:40.921 [main] DEBUG io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop - -Dio.netty.selectorAutoRebuildThreshold: 512
17:19:40.922 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.PlatformDependent - org.jctools-core.MpscChunkedArrayQueue: available
17:19:41.039 [main] DEBUG io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelId - -Dio.netty.processId: 2924 (auto-detected)
17:19:41.041 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.NetUtil - -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack: false
17:19:41.041 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.NetUtil - -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses: false
17:19:41.162 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.NetUtil - Loopback interface: lo (Software Loopback Interface 1, 127.0.0.1)
17:19:41.163 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.NetUtil - \proc\sys\net\core\somaxconn: 200 (non-existent)
17:19:41.321 [main] DEBUG io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelId - -Dio.netty.machineId: e4:b3:18:ff:fe:6c:52:eb (auto-detected)
17:19:41.321 [main] DEBUG i.n.util.internal.ThreadLocalRandom - -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier: 0xb620b93d4006e503
17:19:41.333 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector - -Dio.netty.leakDetection.level: simple
17:19:41.333 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector - -Dio.netty.leakDetection.maxRecords: 4
17:19:41.355 [main] DEBUG i.n.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.numHeapArenas: 2
17:19:41.355 [main] DEBUG i.n.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas: 2
17:19:41.355 [main] DEBUG i.n.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.pageSize: 8192
17:19:41.355 [main] DEBUG i.n.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.maxOrder: 11
17:19:41.355 [main] DEBUG i.n.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.chunkSize: 16777216
17:19:41.355 [main] DEBUG i.n.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.tinyCacheSize: 512
17:19:41.355 [main] DEBUG i.n.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.smallCacheSize: 256
17:19:41.355 [main] DEBUG i.n.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.normalCacheSize: 64
17:19:41.355 [main] DEBUG i.n.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.maxCachedBufferCapacity: 32768
17:19:41.355 [main] DEBUG i.n.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator - -Dio.netty.allocator.cacheTrimInterval: 8192
17:19:41.364 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil - -Dio.netty.allocator.type: pooled
17:19:41.365 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil - -Dio.netty.threadLocalDirectBufferSize: 65536
17:19:41.365 [main] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil - -Dio.netty.maxThreadLocalCharBufferSize: 16384
17:19:41.406 [main] INFO  com.basho.riak.client.core.RiakNode - RiakNode started; 192.168.0.102:8098
17:19:41.407 [main] INFO  c.basho.riak.client.core.RiakCluster - RiakCluster is starting.
17:19:41.408 [main] INFO  c.b.r.c.core.util.DefaultCharset - No desired charset found in system properties, the default charset 'windows-1252' will be used
17:19:41.408 [main] INFO  c.b.r.c.core.util.DefaultCharset - Initializing client charset to: windows-1252
17:19:41.443 [main] DEBUG com.basho.riak.client.core.RiakNode - Attempting to acquire channel permit
17:19:41.445 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.Recycler - -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread: 32768
17:19:41.445 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.Recycler - -Dio.netty.recycler.maxSharedCapacityFactor: 2
17:19:41.445 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.Recycler - -Dio.netty.recycler.linkCapacity: 16
17:19:41.445 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.Recycler - -Dio.netty.recycler.ratio: 8
17:19:41.447 [main] DEBUG com.basho.riak.client.core.RiakNode - Operation 28144878 being executed on RiakNode 192.168.0.102:8098
17:19:41.461 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-10] DEBUG io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf - -Dio.netty.buffer.bytebuf.checkAccessible: true
17:19:41.463 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-10] DEBUG i.n.util.ResourceLeakDetectorFactory - Loaded default ResourceLeakDetector: io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector@1536e36
```

Call stack of suspended thread

```
Thread [main] (Suspended)   
    Unsafe.park(boolean, long) line: not available [native method]  
    LockSupport.park(Object) line: not available    
    CountDownLatch$Sync(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer).parkAndCheckInterrupt() line: not available 
    CountDownLatch$Sync(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer).doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(int) line: not available   
    CountDownLatch$Sync(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer).acquireSharedInterruptibly(int) line: not available 
    CountDownLatch.await() line: not available  
    StoreOperation(FutureOperation<T,U,S>).await() line: 387    
    GenericRiakCommand$1(CoreFutureAdapter<T2,S2,T,S>).await() line: 90 
    StoreValue(RiakCommand<T,S>).execute(RiakCluster) line: 92  
    RiakClient.execute(RiakCommand<T,S>) line: 355  
    Testing.main(String[]) line: 29
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple code addition after the following line of your code should fix things for you:

```
response rv = client.execute(store);
```

add:

```
client.shutdown();
```

to release that connection and continue execution.

**Note** that you will need to create a new connection for your next request against the database since you closed `client` or use `.executeAsync()` in place of `.execute()`.

Comment: But its not going past that line of code. I've also added the callstack of the suspended thread in the question.

Comment: If your code now reads as:
Response rv = client.execute(store); 
client.shutdown();
System.out.println("write done");

The print statement should execute. I have run your code locally with the changes I describe above against a single node successfully.

Comment: sure,ideally it should run successfully because its the reference code in the documentation. But for some reason it doesn't work for me. I was hoping someone could help me find the reason from the log and the callstack of the suspended thread.

Comment: Are you saying it still doesn't work after changing your code to use either .executeAsync() or .shutdown()? Without making those changes the client is waiting for a response to the store operation that won't be coming unless there is an error thrown.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are expecting the Riak java client to connect using HTTP API.  The Riak java client only connects using protocol buffer; using the HTTP address and port will freeze.

Answer (score 0):

Yoy have to use this, its works fine...

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException,
        InterruptedException, UnknownHostException {

    RiakClient client = RiakClient.newClient(8087,"192.168.0.65");

    // put some stuff

    Namespace ns = new Namespace("TestBucket");
    Location location = new Location(ns, "TestKey");

    String myData = "TestValue";

    StoreValue store = new StoreValue.Builder(myData)
    .withLocation(location).build();
    client.execute(store);            // << NEVER GETS PAST THIS

    System.out.println("write done");

 // get some stuff
    FetchValue fv = new FetchValue.Builder(location).build();
    FetchValue.Response response = client.execute(fv);
    String obj = response.getValue(String.class);

    System.out.println(obj);
    System.out.println("fetch done");

}
```

hope you will also get... !!!